# Which enchantments should I use for a maximum DPS archer build following the Ordinator overhaul?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, skyrim-dragonborn

I'm soon to be using the "Miracle" perk that comes with the [**Ordinator perk overhaul**](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1137/?) for SE.

For those unaware, the perk does the following:

"You put your heart and soul into the next item you enchant at an Arcane Nexus, placing up to three enchantments upon it that are 25% stronger. Try as you might, you will never be able to repeat this feat."

What enchantments would one recommend for maximum DPS for a sneaky archer build? I was considering chaos damage, fiery soul trap and frost damage on a Stalhrim bow.

Comment: Stupid didn't get in randomly in my review queue and thus can't vote "leave open." Close voters: A close vote is not a super down vote. There is at least one combination of 3 enchants that will, objectively, maximize DPS. This isn't a great question, but it has a at least one correct objective answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the data available [here](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects#Weapon_Effects), your choices are correct:

Chaos damage applies the base 10 pt. damage to all three elemental effects (triple damage) but with 50% chance, making the average DPS about 1.5 times the damage of using a single elemental effect.

Fiery Soul Trap gives you the standard 10pt. damage that you get from the Fire Damage effect with the added benefit of soul trapping. However the fire effect is NOT augmented by your enchantment skill or perks. It is increased by the Augmented Flames Destruction perk, however.

And Frost damage is beneficial as it slows down the enemy which is useful against the majority of enemies (excluding trolls, frost atronachs and frost wizards), as well as the 10 pt. base damage.

If you are playing a vampire, you can further increase these effects using the Necromage perk (+25% magnitude on enchantments) and by levelling up your enchantment skill and choosing appropriate perks.